# Number.prototype.toLocaleString('en-US') strips ten-thousandth decimal place?

Tags: javascript, locale

In Chrome, if you convert a number to a locale string, it chops off decimal places after the thousandth decimal place:

```
(10.001).toLocaleString('en-US'); // => '10.001'
(10.0001).toLocaleString('en-US'); // => '10'
```

**Primary question:** How do I guard against this?

**Tangential questions:**

1. Is this a bug?
2. Is there a reason I should let it chop off the decimal place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not a bug. By default, toLocaleString includes a maximum of 3 fractional digits. You can include more by specifying an options argument with a larger `maximumFractionDigits` value:

```
(10.0001).toLocaleString('en-US', {maximumFractionDigits:20}); // => '10.0001'
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

> **`minimumFractionDigits`**
>
> The minimum number of fraction digits to use. Possible values are from 0 to 20; the default for plain number and percent formatting is 0.
>
> **`maximumFractionDigits`**
>
> The maximum number of fraction digits to use. Possible values are from 0 to 20; the default for plain number formatting is the larger of `minimumFractionDigits` and 3.